# Django 'generator' object is not subscriptable when using iterator()

Tags: django, iterator

I am trying to optimize my web application by using iterator() on my queryset in an attampt to save memory.

However if I do this:

```
q = (
    Q(longname__icontains = query) |
    Q(genus__icontains = query) |
    Q(specific_epithet__icontains = query) |
    Q(infraspecific_epithet__icontains = query) |
    Q(collectedby__personname__icontains = query) |
    Q(islandname__icontains = query) |
    Q(es_name__icontains = query) |
    Q(en_name__icontains = query) |
    Q(local_name__icontains = query)
)
query_set = Specimen.objects.filter(q).order_by('longname').iterator()[:1000]
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError at /search/
'generator' object is not subscriptable
```

And if I try:

```
query_set.count()
```

I get:

```
AttributeError at /search/
'generator' object has no attribute 'count'
```

My question is - how can I use iterator on this type of query and is it really worth it?

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: I am highly skeptical that the exception came from that code.

Comment: Are you are right - I think it is some processing after that raises the exception. See my edit.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.islice()` to slice a generator. You will need to perform a separate `COUNT(*)` query to get the total number of records returned.

Answer (score 1):

`iterator()` turns a QuerySet to a generator object, which is no longer subscriptable and does not have `.count()` method.
So do slice, and other QuerySet-specific operations, before turning the QuerySet into generator(after that you can only access the generator by iterating on it):

```
query_set = Specimen.objects.filter(q).order_by('longname')[:1000].iterator()
```

Or you could operate on the generator as Ignacio suggested

```
query_set = Specimen.objects.filter(q).order_by('longname').iterator()
from itertools import islice
g = islice(query_set, 1000)
```

Comment: Thankyou! I use the slice syntax to limit the query to a reasonable number to avoid large memory usage. So if I need to count the number of results following slicing, which is the best way to do that? Bare in mind I am shooting for the least memory-intensive option.

Comment: @DarwinTech I'm not quite sure your meaning about *count*, could you provide some details? Or its something like `qs[100:].count()`?  Furthermore, DB backend such as psycopg loads all of the result set into memory, you could check [this](http://www.mellowmorning.com/2010/03/03/django-query-set-iterator-for-really-large-querysets/) to achieve less memory foodprint (remember to use `iterator()` in the loop line in the snippet)

Comment: I basically want to execute the query `query_set = Specimen.objects.filter(q).order_by('longname')[:1000].iterator()` and then get the number of items in the `query_set`.

Comment: @DarwinTech you could maintain a counter when iterating through the generator, or simply `Specimen.objects.filter(q).count()` and compare the result w/ 1000 to get the minimum value.

Comment: If I do another query that means I am hitting the db again just to get the count? Isn't this a waste?

Comment: @DarwinTech It depends on your logic, if you could iterate through the generator, there is no need. If you couldn't in code, `count()` to hit DB is necessary.